# Different results of new vs returning users in regular report and dashboard widget

Tags: google-analytics

In the regular report through menu (Audience/Overview) I get the New vs. Returning visitors ratio 47% vs 53%. But in the dashboard widget the same New vs. Returning visitors ratio is 70% vs 30%. Same segment(s), same date.

Please why is this and which data should I trust? Thank you very much.

Comment: Initially, I thought I'd be able to pinpoint your issue to something involving differing date ranges, differing segmentation, or sampled data.  I've opened the following issue with GA: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71553861

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "Users" as the metric in the dashboard widget?

You must use "Sessions" for it to match the new vs returning report under Audience Overview.

Comment: I tested this and can confirm that I was looking at users, not sessions.  Changing the dashboard widget to look at sessions instead of users did the trick.